# Access OleDB unable to delete

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, sql-delete

```
            string myQuery = "DELETE FROM Child WHERE ChildID = " + int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue) + "";
            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Label2.Text = "Done! " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + " Successful remove";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label2.Text = "Exception in DBHandler" + ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

`ChildID` column is an autonumber primary key.

Wrong sql query?

delete selected dropdownlist that from database

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection.

Comment: First thing to do: use parameterized SQL instead of putting the value directly into the SQL. Next thing to do: show us the rest of your code. You're not actually executing the command in the code you've shown.

Comment: If ID is an int, you can usually skip the single quote characters.

Comment: Since you have not actually asked a question that can be understood without context that is not provided in this question, the question is difficult to answer. It is because of this I am recommending that this question be closed unless it is edited to add details about the specific errors or you explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some code in the example, but try something like the following.

```
string query = "DELETE FROM Child WHERE ChildID = @id";
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
try
{
    myConnection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    if (myConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) myConnection.Close();
}
```